# `deiconify` but without focus

Tags: python, tkinter

After hiding the window with `window.withdraw()`

Using `deiconify`, brings back the window and give it focus.

But I want to only bring the window up. But not give it focus.
And by *bringing it up*, I mean to show above all windows.

How can I do this?

Comment: Simply use `window.iconify()`.

Comment: @May.D This is not a problem with the hiding part. I believe `iconify`()` is for minimizing the window to a `icon`. I need to bring back the window up from `withdraw` or `iconify`, but not give it focus.

Comment: `iconify` will restore the icon in the taskbar after `withdraw` without giving focus to the window.

Comment: @May.D My bad explanation. I meant to **show above other windows**. It seems `iconify` only restore the icon in the taskbar.

Comment: can't you bring it back with deiconify and them just change the focus to another window after that?

Comment: Try using `window.lift()`